# How to create a task for app engine task queue in Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Google's docs omit the most important aspect: How a Task is created. Can anybody complete the sample code:

```
import (
    "appengine/datastore"
    "appengine/taskqueue"
)

func f(c appengine.Context) {
    err := datastore.RunInTransaction(c, func(c appengine.Context) error {
        t := ... // WHY DOES GOOGLE NOT EXPLAIN THIS PART???
        // Use the transaction's context when invoking taskqueue.Add.
        _, err := taskqueue.Add(c, t, "")
        // ...
    })
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/reference#Task) for the `Task` type shows that `Task` is a struct with 10 or so fields, so you probably don't want to construct a Task yourself. However, it also provides the `NewPOSTTask` function (just below that):

> NewPOSTTask creates a Task that will POST to a path with the given form data

I agree the documentation could be much better though.

Comment: You can also use the delay package to handle the encoding -https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/delay#Function.Task

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is described in the docs for [datastore transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/transactions?hl=en).

So the missing code to create a task is:

```
t := &taskqueue.Task{Path: "/path/to/workertask"}
```